# Accessing inner tags data which has no class or id from outer tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the html i have:

```
<iframe id="edit-resp398__ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:""">
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " spellcheck="false" dir="ltr">

<p>I want to Access this</p>
<p>And also this..</p>

</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I only have an id of the iframe which is different for all iframes, the id and class of body stays the same for all the iframes. i want to access the material that is in a particular text area using iframe id. In short, i want to access the body of iframe using iframe id.. How can i do that using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the contents of the iframe is from the same domain you can access it by:

```
$('#edit-resp398__ifr').contents().find(selector)...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
$('#edit-resp398__ifr').find('p:first').text()
```

More about jQuery selectors here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/